# NoMethodError in Checklists#show, undefined method `each' for #<Item:0x007f9e441517d0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to print all items matching a checklist.

I get the error NoMethodError in Checklists#show, undefined method `each'  for #Item:0x007f9e441517d0

Not sure what is causing it, any help would be appreciated.

View:
app/views/checklist/show.html.erb

```
<h1> <%= @checklist.name %> </h1>    
<ul class="item">
        <% @items.each do |item| %>
                <li>
                        <%= item.item_name %>
                        <%= item.eta %>
                        <%= item.complete %>
                </li>
        <% end %>

</ul>
```

Controller: 
app/controller/checklists_controller.rb

```
  def show
        @checklist = Checklist.find(params[:id])
        @items = Item.find_by(checklist_name: @checklist.name)
  end
```

Comment: Change checklist.name to checklist.id in your show action. You are setting checklist_id to a name.

Comment: That is intentional. Checklist_id is a string and should correspond to the name column in the Checklist table. I am correcting the column name checklist_id to checklist_name now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that checklist and items are not associated, and that you will be changing the name of checklist_id to checklist name then the below should work for you. Find_by will only return the first record found. Where will return all records.

```
def show
  @checklist = Checklist.find(params[:id])
  @items = Item.where(checklist_name: @checklist.name)
end
```

Comment: This did it. I knew I had to be missing something right in front of me. I have updated original post such that the lack of association is more clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be in this line:

```
@items = Item.find_by(checklist_id: @checklist.name)
```

Change it to:

```
@items = Item.find_by(checklist_id: @checklist.id)
```

Comment: @checklist.name is actually correct. I want the value for the name column, not the id column. I realized I misnamed the column and have not corrected it in the database yet.

checklist_id is a string and is looking for the name: from Checklist.

Comment: Rails convention is to associate to another table via it's id number. You can then get the name using item.checklist.name.

Comment: Currently the tables are not associated. They probably should be and I will probably correct that shortly.

In this case though `Item.find_by(checklist_id: @checklist.name)` should return an array of items that is stored in @items. Why is @items.each not working?